# Implementing configurable feature-based roles and permissions in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, database-design

I have a scenerio where I am creating custom roles and assigning permissions to them for each fetaure. The process is fully customized and generic and it works for CRUD operations(like create user, read user, update user and delete user) perfectly. Now there is a little change in requirements where I have multiple operations for one feature like create order, accept order, split order, refer order. Now I want to create a roles and permissions so that it covers this part of my problem as well.

Inititally I had four models i.e. Role, Permission, Feature, RoleFeatureAssociation(fields: role, feature, list(permissions)).
I was checking permissions upon each request and if the particular user had that particular permission available for that feature then request was processed.

Keeping this procedure in view as well how should I manage new requirements since I have multiple operations for feature instead of just create, read, update and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation appears to be correct.
It's essential to check each permission before accessing the page. Alternatively, you can create a list or table of endpoints and corresponding user permissions, ensuring that users can access specific endpoints, such as allowing user X to access endpoint A for create and update operations.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of doing the same. But maybe there is a better way, which I'm not aware of. Thanks for the response!!